# SSRS parameter default value from stored procedure does not refresh

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a stored procedure that retrieves a date:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFirstContractFirstDate]
    @Classifierid uniqueidentifier = 'C53387E0-AD2B-E511-9421-005056BAB261' 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        CONVERT(DATE, MIN(o.tisa_RegistrationDate), 103) AS startDate
    FROM 
        Opportunity AS o 
    INNER JOIN
        SystemUserBase AS u ON u.SystemUserId = 'DB159B57-4A3D-E311-93EC-00155D46BF05' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        UserSettingsBase AS us ON us.SystemUserId = u.SystemUserId 
    INNER JOIN
        tisa_Article AS art ON art.tisa_ArticleId = o.tisa_ArticleId 
    INNER JOIN
        tisa_Address AS addr ON addr.tisa_AddressId = art.tisa_AddressId
    WHERE 
        (addr.tisa_ClassifierId = @Classifierid)
```

In my SSRS report I have two parameters `@Classifierid` and `@startDate`.

When I run the report for the first time and when I choose the value for classifierid, I get the date needed, but when I change the value of classifierid, the startDate default value does not get refreshed. The report shows the default date that was retrieved the first time. How can I automatically refresh my parameter `@StartDate`?

First time reports run

[image: First time the report runs]

StartDate has been not refreshed

[image]

Comment: Where is the @StartDate parameter?

Comment: The default value of my startDate parameter is based on the stored procedure above. The parameter startDate is used for another stored procedure to retrieve data

Comment: Ah. Now I understand: this stored procedure shows how the "default value" is chosen for your `Start Date`.  The problem is that your default value is not being refreshed each time. Is that correct?

Comment: Try right clicking the parameter in editor and going to advance and ticking the "Always Refresh" box...

Comment: @tgolisch Yes, It is correct

Comment: @Lucky I'd already tried it. It does not helped me